# passing datetime from objective c to django

Tags: python, objective-c, django, datetime, nsdateformatter

this is my Objective C code:

```
    + (NSString*) stringFromDateTime: (NSDate*) p_date
    {
        NSString* dateStr = @"--/--/--";

        if(p_date != nil)
        {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"];

        dateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:p_date];
        }

        return dateStr;
   }
```

in Django I get the following if I print the variable like this: `print request_data['currentTime']` i get this '27/08/14 01:03:29'.
when I try to save it to my model like this `datetime.datetime.strptime(value['currentTime'], "%dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss")`
I get the following exception:

```
time data '27/08/14 01:03:29' does not match format '%dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss'
```

I've tried this format as well same error: `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`
What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string `"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"` is not in a format understood by python. Your other format `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'` is much closer but you have an uppercase `%Y`, which is equivalent to `yyyy`. Try this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(value['currentTime'], "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

See docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior